# Plone bundle error

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

My log files are filling up with this and I can't figure out where it is coming from.  I'm running Plone 5.  All the log file show is the following:

```
2016-02-02T07:03:19 INFO Products.CMFPlone Error compiling js/css for the bundle
------
2016-02-02T07:03:19 INFO Products.CMFPlone Error compiling js/css for the bundle
```

1. Is there a more in depth log I can use?
2. Has anyone seen this error before and where does it usually stem from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it the same as https://github.com/collective/wildcard.media/issues/37 ?

Comment: I do not believe so.  It has nothing to do with Firefox or videos.  It is happening no matter what browser is being used.

Comment: Have you read it to the end: "The error seems to be in plone.resource.directory.publishTraverse; here there is the NotFound that cause the Error compiling js/css. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down the issue.  It had nothing to do with the error suggested in github.com/collective/wildcard.media/issues/37

For some reason, one of my addons was included in it's own bundle and added as a resource in plone-legacy.  They collided.  Once I dropped one, the errors went away.

So anyone with this issue, check to make sure you don't have any collisions.